# How to declare var datatype in public scope in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I write simple query with linq to sql :

```
var query = (from p in behzad.GAPERTitles
                         select new
                         {
                             p.id,
                             p.gaptitle
                         }).ToArray();
```

up code into the c# windows application ,windows form load event,and i want use up result into the button click event in this scope:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //using var query array in this scope for example string temp=query[i].id
        }
```

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare it as a known type (not an anonymous type), like this for example:

```
Dictionary<int, string> results = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Then you could store the results in the Dictionary:

```
results = behzad.GAPERTitles.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.gaptitle);
```

And reference it later:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use results in this scope, for example: string title = results[someId]
}
```

If the order of the results matter, then a Dictionary won't work. You could use  a Tuple or create a class just for the occasion:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> results = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

...
results = behzad.GAPERTitles.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.One, x.Two)).ToList();

...
// use results, for example:
//    string id = results[i].Item1; string title = results[i].Item2;
```